# jQuery marquee, зациклено бегущая строка

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Есть бегущая строка реализованная через js.
Когда строка доходит до левой границы, содержимое резко перемещается назад.

Нужно чтобы строка уезжала за край, и в этот момента уже начало появляться тоже самое содержимое по второму кругу.

Как на данном видео: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVlBi.jpg
[image: Текст]

Вот что получилось у меня:

[image: Текст]

Comment: Где код ваш css html?

Comment: Извиняюсь, на РУ версии не изменил. Вот ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72440175/jquery-marquee-ticker-looping